# What is the proper syntax to use for @st.cache_data for my webpage?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, streamlit

I have created a webpage that will extract data from a database and and show it as a line chart using streamlit. I recently found out that i can cache the repetitive data using `@st.cache_data`, but I don't understand what the  proper syntax should be in my specific code such that it doesnt throw any errors. Below is the way i have tried to implement it but it is throwing errors related to plotly which has only started to occur after I introduced the st.cache operation to the code so i think it has something to do with the way my code is handling the `datafr_creator()`. Please assist what should be the proper way to cache a dataframe? I couldn't find other implementations where a for loop is used.

```py
#initialize dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

@st.cache_data(ttl=120)
def datafr_creator():
    global df
    for row in supabaseList:
        row["created_at"] = row["created_at"].split(".")[0]
        row["time"] = row["created_at"].split("T")[1]
        row["date"] = row["created_at"].split("T")[0]
        row["DateTime"] = row["created_at"]
        df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    return (df)

datafr_creator()
#creating local list

#Display section
orignal_title = '<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica; color:Black; font-size: 45px; text-align: center">Tridev Water Monitoring System</p>'
st.markdown(orignal_title, unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.text("")
fig = px.area(df, x="DateTime", y="water_level", title='',markers=False)
fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "Water level in %",
        'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'})
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range = [0,120])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range = custom_range)

#Add Horizontal line in plotly chart for pump trigger level
fig.add_hline(y=80, line_width=3, line_color="black",
              annotation_text="Pump Start Level",
              annotation_position="top left",
              annotation_font_size=15,
              annotation_font_color="black"
              )

#Final Chart print
st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True)
```

It is currently throwing this error:

```
ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of [] but received: DateTime
```

I want to cache the dataframe so that on every run the code doesn't have to fetch data from the database, then process it inside the for-loop. All of which is time consuming.

Comment: what does `supabaseList` look like?

Comment: Note that syntax errors have to do with the Python parsing your text file, not runtime. Presumably your syntax is fine if you're able to run this code. Consider using `st.session_state` to do this. If the df isn't in state, generate it, otherwise use the existing one.

Comment: @DerekO the supabaseList consists of 3 columns ID , Created_at & waterlevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `df` does not contain any column named `"DateTime"` here: `fig = px.area(df, x="DateTime", y="water_level", title='',markers=False)`.

It means that for some reason, your dataframe must be empty.

Moreover, you shouldn't use `global` with the cache. It is not necessary. Simply call the `datafr_creator` function with the cache decorator and then, retrieve its result as shown in the [Streamlit docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_data).

It gives:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

@st.cache_data(ttl=120)
def datafr_creator():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for row in supabaseList:
        row["created_at"] = row["created_at"].split(".")[0]
        row["time"] = row["created_at"].split("T")[1]
        row["date"] = row["created_at"].split("T")[0]
        row["DateTime"] = row["created_at"]
        df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    return df

# Here, it will call datafr_creator and use the cache if the
# dataframe has already been generated.
df = datafr_creator()

orignal_title = '<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica; color:Black; font-size: 45px; text-align: center">Tridev Water Monitoring System</p>'
st.markdown(orignal_title, unsafe_allow_html=True)
st.text("")
fig = px.area(df, x="DateTime", y="water_level", title='', markers=False)
fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "Water level in %",
        'y':0.9,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[0, 120])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=custom_range)

# Add Horizontal line in plotly chart for pump trigger level
fig.add_hline(
    y=80, line_width=3, line_color="black",
    annotation_text="Pump Start Level",
    annotation_position="top left",
    annotation_font_size=15,
    annotation_font_color="black"
)

# Final Chart print
st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: This worked! I had called the ```df = pdDataFrame( )``` before the loop & handnt created the ```df``` while calling the ```datafr_creator()``` It solved the problem! seems like a simple mistake in retrospect. Thanks man!